# Codeigniter result_array() returning one row

Tags: sql, codeigniter, model

In my table I have two rows but when I `print_r` the `$data` that this model function is connected to it is only returning the second row in the db why?

**Model Function:**

```
function getAllUsers()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $row['id'];
        $row['fName'];
        $row['lName'];
        $row['email'];
        $row['password'];
    }

    return $row;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$row` is the loop variable, it will only hold the data from the last iteration  after the loop has exited.

Do it like this:

```
function getAllUsers()
{
    $rows = array(); //will hold all results
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {    
        $rows[] = $row; //add the fetched result to the result array;
    }

   return $rows; // returning rows, not row
}
```

**In your controller:**

```
$data['users'] = $this->yourModel->getAllUsers();
$this->load->view('yourView',$data);
```

**In your view**

```
//in your view, $users is an array. Iterate over it

<?php foreach($users as $user) : ?>

<p> Your first name is <?= $user['fName'] ?> </p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks,  How would I fetch the data from the view?  Before I had $data['blah'] = model_function then in the view I had $blah['table_name']

Comment: Thanks @xbonez When using it with html whats the correct syntax for when you use <?php foreach($userDetails as $userDetail):?>