# Database query results comes in a different variable, The reason?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In post [Codeigniter result_array() returning one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026345/codeigniter-result-array-returning-one-row)  https://stackoverflow.com/users/315828/xbonez answer was like this

```
function getAllUsers()
{
$rows = array(); //will hold all results
$query = $this->db->get('users');

foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
{    
    $rows[] = $row; //add the fetched result to the result array;
}

return $rows; // returning rows, not row
}
```

In your controller:

```
$data['users'] = $this->yourModel->getAllUsers();
$this->load->view('yourView',$data);
```

In your view

//in your view, $users is an array. Iterate over it

```
<?php foreach($users as $user) : ?>

<p> Your first name is <?= $user['fName'] ?> </p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

initiating query from controller and the query result is in `$data['users']`, but in view we are iterating in as `$users`. why this is?

Comment: Because you are passing 'users' as key to your 'data' array in your load view function.

Answer (score 2):

`$this->load->view()` function `accepts 2 arguments`, second one is optional. first argument is name of the `view without extension`. and second argument is `array containing key value pairs`. if second argument is passed then `all keys will be converted into variable names` and they will occupy the values which are present in that array

Comment: Thanks.Understood.Thinking,,, this conversion is done by the framework, Not a  feature of language. Right?

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter(or mvc framework such as cakePHP), we build array with key and value in Controller. And then pass it to view as variables.

So `$data['users']=array(key=>val)` will goto view and accessed as `echo $users['key']`.

See carefully All variable keys in controller(such as `$data['users']` here users is key) become Actual variables in view(such as `$users`), which is why we call it MVC structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you set in your controller ,

```
$data['users'] = $this->yourModel->getAllUsers();
$this->load->view('users',$data);    //first argument will be passed to view as $users
```

In your view , you will call about parameter

```
<?php foreach($users as $user) : ?>
<p> Your first name is <?= $user['fName'] ?> </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check `loader.php` in `system/core` and find `"public function view"`, it will answer your question.