# Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on null in line

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting fatal error any one can help me what is wrong with code.?
please help.

```
public function index(){


                $t_name = $this->input->post('t_name');
                $row_id = $this->input->post('change_id');

                if($t_name == ''){
                    $t_name = 'table1';                 
                }
                if($row_id == '')
                {
                    $row_id = 1;
                    //Setup a database connection returning a single row value
                    $this->db->select("*");
                    $this->db->where("Q_Id", $row_id);
                    $query = $this->db->get('table1',1,0);

                    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                        $variable = $query->row("Q_Id");
                        $qu['res'] = $variable;

                    } else {

                    }
                }

                $this->load->view('admin/question_paper_alter' , $qu);
            }
```

view code. I want to print my row in this table field. any one can help me.

```
<?php foreach($res->result_array() as $row):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['rrid']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: what is `$res`? or do you mean `$qu['res']->result_array()`?

Comment: @bansi yes $res comes from controller `$qu['res']` I am new to codeiniter so help me.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347028/codeigniter-call-to-a-member-function-result-array-on-a-non-object

Comment: looks like you need `$qu['res'] = $query;`. I may be wrong (never worked with codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write `result_array();` in query itself.

```
$data= $this->db->get()->result_array();
$i=0;
foreach ($data as $row);
{
       echo $row[$i]->title;
       echo $row[$i]->name;
       $i++;
}
```

`result_array` returns result with array with stdobject

Answer (score 0):

Check https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

result_array() is a method of $query

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['body'];
}
```

try do something like [Codeigniter result_array() returning one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026345/codeigniter-result-array-returning-one-row)

Comment: I do this same but not working. my $query is `$res` comes from controller.

Comment: try $qu['res'] = $query;

Comment: It give me error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' ` when I try to use `$qu['res']`